# Magento 2.2 - Simple Product price incl tax decimal point custom logic

Tags: magento2, product, price

Want to show a simple product price in the following way on the product list and detail page.

1. Magento price: `5623.50` With TAX( 10% ) it’s displayed in the front end
   as : `5623.50 + 562.35 = 6185.85`
2. we will take the decimal value part `(0.85)`
3. Then 1 minus the decimal part `1 - 0.85 = 0.15`
4. Price including TAX + 0.15 = `6185.85 + 0.15 = 6186.00`
5. Customer will pay `6186.00`

Till now used `afterGetPrice` plugin method.

```
namespace Pr\Ro\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;

class Product
{

    public function afterGetPrice( ProductInterface $subject, $result ) {
        return calculateLogiceMagentoPrice($result);
        //return $result;
    }

    public function calculateLogiceMagentoPrice( $price )
    {       
        $whole = floor($price);         
        $fraction = $price - $whole;
        $minus_decimal = 1 - $fraction;     
        $finalPrice = $price + $minus_decimal;              
        return $finalPrice;
    }   

}
```

tried with `"Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils"` and '[PriceModifiers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144107/magento-2-use-of-pricemodifiers)' also